# Sort between 1.1 and 1.1.2

Tags: python, data-analysis, data-cleaning

In data analysis we get a situation like a data is `1.1` and another like `1.1.2` where we have to sort the data

but it cannot understand the second data as a number it only looks for first number.
Is there a hack to sort this data...

Comment: What type is `1.1` in this case?

Comment: Please provide a more extensive input example with desired output if you expect a useful answer. For now, you can try searching for 'Python version sorting'.

Comment: Try `sorted(['1.1', '1.0.10' '1.2', '1.0', '1.10.01'], key=lambda s: [int(e) for e in s.split('.')])`

Answer (score 2):

Use a lambda with `sorted`, splitting on `'.'` and mapping each section to `int`.

```
>>> lst = ["1.1.2", "3.4.5", "1.1"]
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: [int(y) for y in x.split('.')])
['1.1', '1.1.2', '3.4.5']
>>>
```